# Repeat innerHTML.replace

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, caption, captions

I'm using the code below to make links linkable in WordPress captions. For example it successfully turns `http://google.com` into [google.com](http://google.com). But when I put multiple url's in a caption it only changes the first one. Is there a way to make it repeat the action on all the links?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery().ready(function() {
    jQuery("p.wp-caption-text").each(function(n) {
        this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.replace(new RegExp(" http://([^ ]*) "), " <a href=\"http://$1\">$1</a> ");
    });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RegExp by default only finds one match.

`this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.replace(new RegExp(" http://([^ ]*) ", "g"), " <a href=\"http://$1\">$1</a> ");`

Adding the "g" flag performs a global match.

Answer (score 2):

A subtle change to your `RegExp` call should do it:

```
    jQuery().ready(function() {
        jQuery("p.wp-caption-text").each(function(n) {
            $(this).html($(this).html().replace(new RegExp(" http://([^ ]*) ", 'g'), " <a href=\"http://$1\">$1</a> "));
        });
    });
```

The key is the `'g'` modifier argument -- `g` stands for global; in other words: replace all.

Here's the relevant reference material: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_g.asp

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.replace.replace(/http:\/\/([^ ]*)/g, " <a href=\"http://$1\">$1</a> ");
```

the /g means that this regular expression is global.